# Xul's window.blur() doesn't work? Is there an alternative?

Tags: window, xul, blur, xulrunner

I'm trying to use [window.blur()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.blur) to open a window without focus it (or focus and unfocus really fast, so looks like it was not focused).

But it looks like it doesn't work, is there an alternative?

**My attempt:**

blurTest.xul:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<window width="400" height="300"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <script>
        <![CDATA[
            function onkeypress(event) {
                // for this sample don't matter which key is pressed
                open('second.xul','SecondWindow','chrome, width=400, height=300');
            }
            addEventListener("keypress", onkeypress, false);
        ]]>
    </script>

    <label value="MAIN WINDOW"/>

</window>
```

second.xul:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<window width="400" height="300"
    onload="blur();"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <label value="SECOND" />

</window>
```

**Obs.** We can think about use setTimeout(window.focus, 1) to call the focus back the my window after open the second window. But I need the second window to handle the focus. The perfect scenario would be if the second window was never able to get the focus, just open/restore the window without get focus.

Comment: As far as I know, ordinary windows always activate when they are shown, only popup windows (menus, dropdowns, alerts etc.) don't.

Comment: @Neil Yes they do, and I want to show a information in a new window, in front of any other window (so the other question about always on top) and I want this new information window to do not get the focus, so the user can continue, for example, typing to a field.

Comment: @Neil popups are not an option, becouse Xul's popups will be hidden when another window is openned. So I need to do my pop-up-like using an always-on-top window that don't get focus.. Would be cool if Xul provides a way to make popups that get in front of every window (I mean, every window of the Xul app at least)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a XUL window as if it was a popup by using the `popup` window feature in the `openDialog` call. This should open a topmost window that doesn't steal focus. Note that by default a popup window has no OS chrome; on Windows you can add the `titlebar` feature (which gives you a mini title bar as for a palette window) and the `close` button (in conjunction with the title bar), but I don't know which feature flags work on other platforms.

Desktop alerts still use this feature on Windows but I believe on Linux they now use libnotify and on the Mac they use Growl.

Comment: +1 The idea is perfect, but, maybe becouse I'm openning it from a fully transparent window, it will no close with `hidePopup()`. Any idea how can I close/hide it programatically? `close()` also don't work..

Comment: ops, the `close()` works.. I had a typo with no error message on the method call..

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still stealing the focus opening with `openDialog('top.xul', 'TopWindow', 'chrome, popup');`

Comment: @Tom Brito Sorry, but it worked for me when I tried it from the Error Console, on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: @Neil ops, errors of a low encapsulated code of mine.. you are correct.

Comment: @Neil by the way, I still would like to use `blur()` for some tasks, do you know how can I get the last focused (not last opened) window, so I can make my own `blur()`?

Comment: The most recently focused window is just the most recent window: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIWindowMediator#getMostRecentWindow%28%29 unfortunately the previously focused window is not exposed by the window mediator.